# How to setup HSTS for FitNesse wiki server

Tags: fitnesse, hsts

I would like to enforce the use of Strict-Transport-Security header (HSTS) on the FitNesse wiki web server responses. Is there a way to configure the web server for this ?

I have already configured HTTPS successfully - but this has no impact to the response' headers.